# Create a SFTP connection in Netbeans

Tags: sftp, netbeans, remote-connection

I'm trying to create a remote connection with a Apache server in netbeans through a SFTP connection using [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html). My intention is upload my files to the server with the IDE.

Following, see the configuration:
[image: Netbeans configuration]

When I test my connection with the server, I see the error `ProxySOCKS5:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out`

I found [some](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209362) [bugs](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201449) with related issues, but any of them helped me to understand my problem. Some of them indicates that the problem is in the server.

I'm able to connect with the same server using FileZilla, SSH and many other softwares, so the problem apparently is not in the server and is not typo or wrong password too (this also excludes problems with the proxy).

Someone had the same problem?

Important information:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- JDK 1.8.0_60
- NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (fresh installation)
- I'm using Cnltm to connect with the enterprise proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Netbeans Bug 251641 - Algorithm negotiation fail for any SFTP connection](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251641)
may apply to your problem. The solution in Comment 5 says :

> Netbeans 7.3 Bets 2 uses JSch library 1.0.45.
>   This version do not work with OpenSSH 6.7.
>   It works only with OpenSSH 6.6.1 and earlier versions.
>
> But JSch library 1.0.52 works with OpenSSH 6.7
>
> 1. Download this version
> 2. Rename current file to backup
>      `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\com-jcraft-jsch.jar`
>      rename to
>      `com-jcraft-jsch.jar.1.0.42.bak`.
> 3. Copy downloaded `com-jcraft-jsch.jar` of version 1.0.52 to this folder
> 4. Restart Netbeans
>
> Bingo!! SSH works again and works with OpenSSH 6.7 servers

Comment 8 says :

> Thank you! Same problem was in 8.0.2 & OpenSSH 6.7

Comment: Thx! It works! Just for information, the default path in Ubuntu can be /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/ide... or /opt/netbeans-8.0.2/ide...

Answer (score 0):

CommonsHTTPSender does persistent connections.

What's your timeout (not connection timeout) set to ? the default of 60 seconds might be a bit low to create a 1 million row cursor. The 2 timeouts you're fiddling with are connection related, and are not relevant in this case (as you have a connection).

Comment: Are you talking about the timeout set in Netbeans? If so, I changed it right now to 90, but the problem persists. I'll update my question with my config. Maybe it helps